# Vue 3, get props in setup

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have some problems getting props value (that is array actually) into my composition api (setup).
So I have component that is called DropDown, and I'm passing it some array of objects, and I need to do something like this:

```
export default {
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  props: {
    items: {
      type: Array,
      // required: true
    },
    modelValue: {
      type: [String, Number, Boolean],
      required: true
    }
  },

  setup({modelValue, props} : any, {emit} : any ) {
    let is_active = ref(false);
    let selected = ref({
        label: props.items[0].label,
        icon: props.items[0].icon,
        class: props.items[0].class
    });
```

as you see I have `let selected` that must have first object of items array, but it's not working. I'm listing items without problem on my template, but on setup I can't.
Any ideas how to fix it?

btw: Best practise is to use like `let selected = reactive(props.items[0])` but, it's not working like this as well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your `setup()` is destructuring a `props` property from the `props` argument.

```js
           props argument
      -------------------------
setup({modelValue, props} : any, {emit} : any) {
                   ^^^^^ ❌ props.props does not exist
```

However, destructuring the `props` argument should be avoided (as [warned in the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#props)) because it removes the reactivity of the destructured prop.

The fix is to remove the destructuring from the `props` argument. Also, you can enable type inference for the `props` and `context` arguments by using the [`defineComponent()` helper function](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/global-api.html#definecomponent) from `vue` to define the component:

```js
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup(props, context) {
    let selected = ref({
      label: props.items[0].label,
      icon: props.items[0].icon,
      class: props.items[0].class
    });

    //...
  }
})
```